# WebDAV Browsing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, webdav

Using C#/ASP.Net I'm creating Virtual Directories in IIS7 so that external people can browse various documents.

It's all looking good, except the browsing is in a dull text format. How can I create more of a "Windows Explorer" look and feel when they browse to the folder.

Thanks in advance,

Jim

Comment: any chance i can get a copy of this code ... i think it would be helpful in a document management system in building. I'll even look at solving this with you :)  ... if my suspicions are correct the output is the result of a server page call so you should be able to override the response.

Answer (score 3):

Probably IT Hit Ajax File Browser will help: http://ajaxbrowser.com. It has explorer- very like user interface